# MySQL order by 0 then largest

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to do a mysql sort that displays `0` first and then by the largest number.

My current mysql statement returns

```
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

But I would like to get this

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Is it possible to build a MySQL query that orders an integer from largest to smallest with `0` at the beginning?

Comment: @bernie What do you mean use a case statement? Could you direct me to the duplicate? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Actually it looks like Gordon has provided a superior solution. I've deleted my previous comment. Happy coding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this `order by` statement:

```
order by val = 0 desc, val desc
```

The first part is a boolean that evaluates to "1" when the value is 1 and otherwise 0.  The second orders the rest of the values in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use 2 filters

```
select * from mytable
order by mycolumn=0 desc, mycolumn desc
```